# Save data to another excel workbook after button click using macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 workbooks: the main.xlsm (main workbook) and backup.xlsx (backup). Now what I want is to save a backup copy to backup.xlsx upon clicking a button using macro. I have the code below, but I don't know why it wouldn't work.

```
Sub ToggleEvents(blnState As Boolean)
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = blnState
        .EnableEvents = blnState
        .ScreenUpdating = blnState
        If blnState Then .CutCopyMode = False
        If blnState Then .StatusBar = False
    End With
End Sub

Function WbOpen(wbName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WbOpen = Len(Workbooks(wbName).Name)
End Function

Sub Transfer()
Dim c As Integer
Dim Ws1 As Worksheet, Ws2 As Worksheet

Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim FilePath As String, FileName As String
Dim blnOpened As Boolean

'the next two refer to the destination file path and filename
FilePath = "C:\Newfolder\"
FileName = "backup.xlsx"

Call ToggleEvents(False)
    If WbOpen(FileName) = True Then
    Set Ws2 = Workbooks("backup.xlsx").Sheets("RAW")
    blnOpened = False
    Else
        If Right(FilePath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
            FilePath = FilePath & Application.PathSeparator
        End If
        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & FileName, , , , "backup.xlsx")
        Set Ws2 = Workbooks("backup.xlsx").Sheets("RAW")


        blnOpened = True
    End If

    Set Ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ProdTracker")

c = 2
Do While Ws2.Range("A" & c) <> ""
    c = c + 1
    Loop
    Ws2.Range("A" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA2")
    Ws2.Range("B" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA3")
    Ws2.Range("C" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA42")
    Ws2.Range("D" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA4")
    Ws2.Range("E" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA5")
    Ws2.Range("F" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA6")
    Ws2.Range("G" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA7")
    Ws2.Range("H" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA8")
    Ws2.Range("I" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA9")
    Ws2.Range("J" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA10")
    Ws2.Range("K" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA11")
    Ws2.Range("L" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA12")
    Ws2.Range("M" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA13")
    Ws2.Range("N" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA14")
    Ws2.Range("O" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA15")
    Ws2.Range("P" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA16")
    Ws2.Range("Q" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA17")
    Ws2.Range("R" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA18")
    Ws2.Range("S" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA19")
    Ws2.Range("T" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA20")
    Ws2.Range("U" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA21")
    Ws2.Range("V" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA22")
    Ws2.Range("W" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA23")
    Ws2.Range("X" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA24")
    Ws2.Range("Y" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA25")
    Ws2.Range("Z" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA26")
    Ws2.Range("AA" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA27")
    Ws2.Range("AB" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA28")
    Ws2.Range("AC" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA29")
    Ws2.Range("AD" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA30")
    Ws2.Range("AE" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA31")
    Ws2.Range("AF" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA32")
    Ws2.Range("AG" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA33")
    Ws2.Range("AH" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA34")
    Ws2.Range("AI" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA35")
    Ws2.Range("AJ" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA36")
    Ws2.Range("AK" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA37")
    Ws2.Range("AL" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA38")
    Ws2.Range("AM" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA39")
    Ws2.Range("AN" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA40")
    Ws2.Range("AO" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA41")
    Ws2.Range("AP" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA43")
    Ws2.Range("AQ" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA44")
    Ws2.Range("AR" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA45")
    Ws2.Range("AS" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA46")
    Ws2.Range("AT" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA47")
    Ws2.Range("AU" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA48")
    Ws2.Range("AV" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA49")
    Ws2.Range("AW" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA50")
    Ws2.Range("AX" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA51")
    Ws2.Range("AY" & c) = Ws1.Range("AA52")


        If blnOpened = True Then
        wkb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give us some clues - perhaps which line it crashes on and the error message, or (if it runs but doesn't do what you expect) what isn't happening that you expect to happen or what is happening that you aren't expecting.

Comment: Its just not doing anything and no errors displayed when clicking the button. By the way macro is embedded to the button and this should be working. Is there any wrong on my codes?

Comment: Go to the VBA "Immediate Window" and enter `?Application.EnableEvents`.  Does it return `True` or does it return `False`?

Comment: @YowE3K It says True.

Comment: Place a `MsgBox "Hello"` just after the `Sub Transfer` line (I assume your button is invoking the `Transfer` subroutine) and see whether the `MsgBox` is displayed when you click the button.

Comment: It did not prompt when i click the button.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/s855mdbl1w9h2jz/main.rar here is my document link if you wanted to check.

Comment: Can you confirm that the button has `Transfer` assigned to it as the macro to run.  (I'm not going to open a macro-enabled file from an unknown internet site.)

Comment: Yes it is assign to a butto.

Comment: I'm rapidly running out of ideas!  I assume you are using a "Forms Control" button (otherwise it would need a `Button_Click` type event, rather than being connected to `Transfer`) so right-click on the button, select "Assign Macro".  In the dialog box that should appear, you should see an "Edit" button on the right-hand side.  Click that and make sure you end up in your `Transfer` code.

Comment: @YowE3K,  This button is an activeX cotrol not a Form Control. But this button is embedded to run the macro (transfer). this was working before and now its just suddenly stop.

Comment: Right-click the button and select `View Code` - what code does it take you to?  I would have thought it should take you to something like `CommandButton1_Click` (where "CommandButton1" is the name of the control), so I am rather surprised that you say it is linked to `Transfer`.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you are assigning data to ws2 workbook and after that you save/close wkb. I think adding wkb to the loop would fo the job.

Comment: `ws2` is a `Worksheet` object that the OP has set to refer to one particular worksheet within `wkb` which is a `Workbook` object.  So saving the workbook referred to by `wkb` is saving all worksheets within that workbook, including the one referred to by `ws2`.